# Prototype.js error message in IE8: 'text' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I'm creating a left menu navigation having tree structure link using prototype.js
In my below code .text property is throwing this error for IE8 browser only. 
How to resolve it?

```
prepareFourthMenu: function(level, body) {
        if(!Object.isFunction(this.currentData.fourth[level])) {
            var items = this.currentData.fourth.item(level);
            for (var x=0; x < items.length; x++) {
                var fourthLevelRow = body.appendRow({ id: 'TR_Second_'+level+x });
                str = "";
                if(x == this.getPointer('fourth')){
                    str = 'nOrange';
                    items[x].func();
                } else {
                    str = 'nBlue';
                }

                fourthLevelRow.insert(new Element("TD", { "class" : str, "id" : "TD_Dummy_"+level+x}));
                link = new Element("A", {"href":"javascript:void(0)","class": str, "style":"text-decoration: none;"})
                    .update("&raquo;  " + items[x].text);
                Event.observe(link, 'click', function(e) { menuObject.updateFourthMenu(arguments[0], arguments[1])}.bindAsEventListener(link, level));
                fourthLevelRow.insert(new Element("TD",{id: 'TD_Second_'+level+x, "class": "FourthLevelNav fourthLevelLink"}).update(link));
            }
        }

    },
```

Throwing Webpage error window
Do you want to debug this site?
This webpage contains error that might prevent it from displaying or working correctly.
Line: 541
Error: Unable to get property 'text' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Seems `items[x]` is null or undefined.

Comment: Either `items[x]` is null or undefined as @Thilo says or `items[x].text` is not a property of one of the objects in the list

Comment: @GeekNum88: You would not get this error message for the second case.

Comment: Thanks to All.. but items already defined here var items = this.currentData.fourth.item(level); 
str = 'nOrange';
                    items[x].func();

And also it is working fine across other browser except IE8

Comment: Well you did assign something but that does not mean it was an array, or it might lack one of the items. Please do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(items))` for us

Answer (score 0):

.text is a property native from jquery,

you can use next code to add this new method, previous to call method

```
 Class.extend(Element, {
  text: function(element) {
    return element.innerHTML.stripTags();
  }
};
```